# Laravel Excel file is not downloading to screen

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm creating a Laravel project using the Maatwebsite Excel package. I have the following line in my Controller when user lands on this url:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;    
public function test()
    {
        return Excel::download($objectArray,'test.xlsx');
    }
```

When I do the following `dd(Excel::download($objectArray,'test.xlsx')` in my method I see a file is created - or at least I think there is - as the result shows a `BinaryFileResonse` object with data. So I can assume the file is being generated, but it isn't being returned/downloaded.

Do I need to pass and grab the url of this file into my `public function index()` method as template data?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is $objectArray?

Answer (score 0):

Is your download route pointing to test() function?

If so, it should be working.

The one thing that I see is this:

```
public function test()
{
    return Excel::download($objectArray,'test.xlsx');
}


function export()
{
    $this->test();
}
```

In the above case you should have

```
return $this->test();
```

Just something that happended to me once.

Comment: can you explain what the `Route` would look like? Currently, my `Route` calls the constructor where it returns the method of `test()`

Comment: Don't know your controller name, but: $router->get('/export_my_stuff', 'MyController@export');